# Not getting 'e' argument

Tags: google-apps-script

```js
function onDraftMessage(e) {
  var draftBody =  e.messageBody;
  var expandedBody = expandShortNames(draftBody);
 // Update the draft with expanded text
 updateDraft(e.draftId, expandedBody);
}

function expandShortNames(text) {
  var spreadsheetId = '1j9hm3mXBJUjFE8N8wjT4sP1cczH40VrmTDVEluivDDs';
  var sheetName = 'Sheet1';
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  
  // Create a dictionary for easy lookup
  var nameMap = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    nameMap[values[i][0]] = values[i][1];
  }
  
  // Replace short names with their corresponding full names
  for (var shortName in nameMap) {
    var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + shortName + '\\b', 'gi');
    text = text.replace(regex, nameMap[shortName]);
  }
  
  return text;
}


function updateDraft(draftId, updatedBody) {
  var draft = GmailApp.getDraft(draftId);
  var message = draft.getMessage();
  var updatedDraft = message.createDraft(updatedBody);
  draft.deleteDraft();
}
```

code:

```
function onDraftMessage(e) {
  var draftBody = e.messageBody;
  var expandedBody = expandShortNames(draftBody);
}

function expandShortNames(text) {
  var spreadsheetId = '1j9hm3mXBJUjFE8N8wjT4sP1cczH40VrmTDVEluivDDs';
  var sheetName = 'Sheet1';
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  var nameMap = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    nameMap[values[i][0]] = values[i][1];
  }
  for (var shortName in nameMap) {
    var regex = new RegExp('\b' + shortName + '\b', 'gi');
    text = text.replace(regex, nameMap[shortName]);
  }
  return text;
}

function updateDraft(draftId, updatedBody) {
  var draft = GmailApp.getDraft(draftId);
  var message = draft.getMessage();
  var updatedDraft = message.createDraft(updatedBody);
  draft.deleteDraft();
}
```

Comment: e is typically used as the first and mostly only argument in a function that is executed by a trigger.  The  e get's populated with the triggers event object.  If you are running the function from the script editor then you must use an intermediate function to supply the event object. - [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)